# oracle query talend etl

Tags: etl, talend

I am a beginner to use talend etl I would make a request to select a database oracle then make a change _ S and insert it into a mysql table I'm stuck. I have not found how to make select queries with talend not know how I started that can help me please

Answer (score 1):

To make a select on Oracle schema you need a tOracleInput component instance. You need to specify a Oracle connection (either a builtin connection or a repository-registered connection) and the output schema (the columns you need).

Then, click on "Guess query" to build the select SQL code accordingly to your desired output schema. You can then modify the automatically generated SQL code to fit your needs (ie. add WHERE or SORT clauses). Don't forget that output schema and selected columns must be the same (ie if you add a SQL-generated column inside the select clause you must add in your output schema, too). Any valid SELECT syntax can be used here (including subselects, cursors, window over partition and even more weird oracle stuff).

After the input instance, add a tMap where you make all your data manipulations. Finally, close with a tMySqlOutput, specifing connection and output table details. The flow will trivially looks like:

```
tOracleInput ----> tMap ----> tMySqlOutput
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the connection Mysql and Oracle in Metadata Objects (Db Connections).

[image]

2. Create the following objects (tMySqlConnection - TOracleConnection)

[image]

3. Configure the objects with the parameters connections (Property Type: Repository).

[image]

4. Extract data: You can select the table with the object tOracleInput.

[image]

5. Edit schema of the table in the submenu Component

[image]

6. Create object TMAP, (transform the data)

[image]

7. Create object tMysqlOutPut and configure the schema and columns to insert.

[image]

[image]

8. Create object tMysqlCommit and close the connection.

[image]

9. Listo!  ¡¡Run to job!! :)